# How to block a POST curl request

Tags: spam, curl, htaccess

My WordPress website received a couple of fake subscriptions to the newsletter. I identified the logs, most of them with the same form as below:

```
xx.xx.xx.xx example.com - [04/Feb/2023:06:01:42 +0100] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 207 "https://example.com/" "curl/7.54.0"
```

Is there any way to block this?

- Could I do that through htaccess?
- And how?
- Or by inserting a PHP script in my WordPress header?

Comment: It looks like this bot is using curl simply to post to your form handling script, without requesting the form first.  To block this without using a captcha, you can stuff a value in a hidden field of the form that changes every time.  Then, add logic to your form handling script to check that this value is present and correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not trust the `User-Agent` header; the circumvention is as easy as the protection. Even with cURL it is possible to change the header with a single command line option.

```
curl -A "Mozilla/5.0 (...) ..."
curl --user-agent "Mozilla/5.0 (...) ..."
curl -H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (...) ..."
```

Use some CAPTCHA, instead. There are WordPress plugins for CAPTCHA, too.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Before using captcha, I will try with htaccess and php solutions. But yes, you're right. This is the simplest way to avoid any crawler to post on the website.

Answer (score 2):

The log record that you posted shows that these requests are being sent with `curl/7.54.0` as the user agent string in the headers of these requests.

In PHP, you can use the `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` environment variable to access the user agent string sent by the client in the request headers.  So, you can insert a simple `if` statement in your PHP script to check the user agent string, and exit if it sees a request with a user agent string that you deem to be unauthorized.

But, bear in mind that the user agent string is set by the client (see the -A option with curl).  Therefore, a determined client can circumvent your check by spoofing a user agent string that you authorize (such as `Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:108.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/108.0`), and continue to make these automated requests to your site.

Answer (score 2):

You can block the cURL request in two ways one using .htacess and another one from your codebase, Check the below .htaccess configuration:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} POST
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^curl [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [R=403,L]
```

The second way is to use `REQUEST_METHOD` and `HTTP_USER_AGENT` in your codebase:

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST' && strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'curl') !== false) {
  header('HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden');
  exit;
}
?>
```

If the request gets blocked and the attacker intends to attack more they might change the user agent to bypass this configuration: [ref](https://reqbin.com/req/c-ekublyqq/curl-user-agent#:%7E:text=Setting%20the%20User%2DAgent%20for,number%22.)

To mitigate this issue, you might add a rate limit on your newsletter if you are getting too many requests at a time ( not sure you didn't mention it ).

Comment: Thank you! It was exactly what I was looking for. I will try that out and look at my logs to see if everything is going back to normal. Actually, the request is coming on night and not so often yet... that you can think that it's a real subscription. I assume the tempo would be going high.

Comment: Understood, Now that you implement this it will mitigate this issue right away.

Comment: It still receive emails from this line above. I assume the robot goes over htaccess. I put the php script in my header but still the same... May I say to my htacess the following: if the ip address comes from US and the http post is curl/7.54.0, then... forbidden? and how? Thx in advance.

Comment: It may happen .htaccess rules are processed before PHP scripts are executed. I will suggest removing the .htaccess and keeping the PHP script and making sure you implement it on top of your WordPress site's index.php file or a commonly included file that is loaded for all pages on your site.

The IP address might come from any region that might not help you at some point in my opinion. Let me know if you using any specific plugin for a newsletter.

Comment: The plugin for newsletter is sendinblue. But, I think I found a way to rid off this curl/7.54.0. I exclude the GET too. I observed in the logs that before the POST, there were 2 GET (301 and 200). I've tried this way and it seems to work even if I should admit that it's weird. I haven't seen it since. I kept the php method and delete the htaccess instructions as you adviced. I still open my eyes. Thanks anyway for your help. Very usefull.